# PL-SQL Query : Difference in values based on date from same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need some help with sql.

| ID | Date | Price1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-09-2020 | 32 |
| 1 | 02-09-2020 | 343 |
| 2 | 03-09-2020 | 54543 |
| 2 | 03-09-2020 | 43232 |
| 2 | 05-09-2020 | 3232 |
| 2 | 05-09-2020 | 34323 |
| 3 | 06-09-2020 | 3234213 |
| 3 | 07-09-2020 | 3232213 |

I have a table of this kind. I want to have difference in price based on dates. Like below

| A.id | date 1 | price 1 | B.ID | date 2 | price 2 | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 03/09/2020 | 54543 | 2 | 05/09/2020 | 3232 | -51311 |
| 2 | 03/09/2020 | 43232 | 2 | 05/09/2020 | 34323 | -8909 |

But I am getting is

| A.id | date 1 | price 1 | B.ID | date 2 | price 2 | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 03/09/2020 | 54543 | 2 | 05/09/2020 | 3232 | -51311 |
| 2 | 03/09/2020 | 54543 | 2 | 05/09/2020 | 34323 | -20220 |
| 2 | 03/09/2020 | 43232 | 2 | 05/09/2020 | 3232 | -40000 |
| 2 | 03/09/2020 | 43232 | 2 | 05/09/2020 | 34323 | -8909 |

i.e the price 1 column in repeating and taking difference for other values

```sql
Select a.id,a.date,a.price,b.id,b.date,b.price,(b.price-a.price)
from xyz a,xyz b      -- same table
where a.id = 2
and a.id = b.id
and a.date = todate(03092020,'ddmmyyyy') and b.date = todate(05092020,'ddmmyyyy')
orderby a.id,a.date
```

This is the code I'm using. All I need is diff in corresponding values

Comment: What is the logic that determines which of the two rows for id = 2 for 03/09/2020 matches which row for the 05/09/2020?

Comment: You need to order and number rows within the same `ID, Date`  and compare rows based on `ID, OrdNumber`

Comment: @Boneist there is a column name position but it's the same values. thing is  there is exact 2 price values for every date and i want difference between first and the corresponding first value and same for second.

Comment: @ShubhamPandey you need to be able to say why the row with price 54543 matches with the row with price 3232, and not the row with price 34323. Once you have that logic (which might be "order the rows from lowest to highest price" or whatever), you can then use that in the join clause in your query.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the price difference you must get the *previous* price in the first step.

To get it you use preferably the [LAG](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LAG.html) analytic function that can lookup the value from the preceeding row.

Before the use you must decide the *partitioning*, i.e. the column(s) that distinct the observed value - in you case the `ID`  and

the column(s) that define ordering - in you case the *date* colum.

Query returns the LAG value

```
select ID, DT, PRICE,
lag(PRICE) over (partition by ID order by DT) PRICE_LAG
from tab
order by ID, DT;


        ID DT                       PRICE  PRICE_LAG
---------- ------------------- ---------- ----------
         1 01.09.2020 00:00:00         32           
         1 02.09.2020 00:00:00        343         32
         2 03.09.2020 00:00:00      54543           
         2 04.09.2020 00:00:00      43232      54543
         2 05.09.2020 00:00:00       3232      43232
         2 06.09.2020 00:00:00      34232       3232
         3 06.09.2020 00:00:00    3234213           
         3 07.09.2020 00:00:00    3232213    3234213
```

The next step is a simple calculation of the difference using

```
PRICE - lag(PRICE) over (partition by ID order by DT) PRICE_DIFF
```

**Important note** - a good practice while making such processing is to validate that the *partitioning* and *ordering* column togather build a *unique key* in the table. (In other words in your case each product at some tiem has a *unique* price).

**Your data violates this** so you may decide to re-thing the approach or clean the data.

Comment: Your sample data are quite different from OP. Have you tried the query using OP sample?

Comment: This is completely different to the OP's question as the OP appears to be comparing the "first" row from 2020-09-03 to the "first" row from 2020-09-05 and the same for the "second" row (ignoring the non-deterministic nature of result sets and that the OP has no way of defining which of the rows should be "first" or "second"). This answer compares the rows based on the previous date.

Comment: @marmite bomber Thanks for your help. Unfortunately couldn't share the real data o.w it's just some minor trick i guess. There is no issues with the database.

Comment: The *core* of my answer @MTO is: Use `LAG` to get the previous value and check that the columns in *partition* plus *order by* makes a *unique key*. If the data does not allow it, some amendment must be done (e.g. new *row_number* column), but this must be done by the data owner, no answer is possible…

Answer (score 1):

You can number the rows for each id/date partition and then pivot the rows to columns based on the dates:

```sql
SELECT id AS id1,
       "1_DATE" AS date1,
       "1_PRICE" AS price1,
       id AS id2,
       "2_DATE" AS date2,
       "2_PRICE" AS price2,
       "2_PRICE" - "1_PRICE" AS diff
FROM   (
  Select x.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, "DATE" ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS rn
  from   xyz x
  where  id = 2
  and    "DATE" IN (DATE '2020-09-03', DATE '2020-09-05')
)
PIVOT (
  MAX("DATE") AS "DATE",
  MAX(price1) AS price
  FOR "DATE" IN (
    DATE '2020-09-03' AS "1",
    DATE '2020-09-05' AS "2"
  )
);
```

*Note: The order of rows is non-deterministic so relying on `ROWNUM` to specify the order is a bad idea as it can change; however, the sample data in the question does not provide any "better" way of determining which rows for 2020-09-3 or 2020-09-05 should be "first" or "second". You should fix your table structure to ensure that there is a way to deterministically order the rows, such as having a `position` column and use that in place of `ROWNUM`.*

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE xyz (ID, "DATE", Price1) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-09-01',      32 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-09-02',     343 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-09-03',   54543 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-09-03',   43232 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-09-05',    3232 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-09-05',   34323 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2020-09-06', 3234213 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2020-09-07', 3232213 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID1 | DATE1 | PRICE1 | ID2 | DATE2 | PRICE2 | DIFF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2020-09-03 00:00:00 | 54543 | 2 | 2020-09-05 00:00:00 | 3232 | -51311 |
| 2 | 2020-09-03 00:00:00 | 43232 | 2 | 2020-09-05 00:00:00 | 34323 | -8909 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6Ayf0xeB)